# setFrom function from elastic search is not working

Tags: elasticsearch

The code I'm using is:

```
 client.prepareSearch(Indices)
                            .setTypes(Type)
                            .setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
                            .setQuery(query)
                                    .setScroll(new TimeValue(1000))
                                    .setSize(1).setFrom(1)
                            .execute().actionGet();
```

My problem is that `setFrom()` is not working.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `scan` search type, only the `size` parameter is used in order to specify how many results to return for each scroll search. `from` is useless in this context.

See detailed info at [Efficient scrolling with Scroll-Scan](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-scan)

Also note that the `scan` search type [has been deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/breaking_21_search_changes.html#_literal_search_type_scan_literal_deprecated) in ES 2.1, simply doing a scroll request does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  This is useful for me